# Can't change property of a parsed HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `input of type checkbox` string which its `checked` property should be set to `true` in a certain condition . the problem I have is that **jQuery** doesn't change the property .

Here is the code :

```
//some code
//*********
value = ['<input type="checkbox" class="checkable" name="ids" value="315658">'];

value[0] = $(value[0]).prop('checked', true).prop('outerHTML'));

console.log(value[0]);//logs the original input HTML which is <input type="checkbox" class="checkable" name="ids" value="315658">

return value;
```

How can I change the string properties with jQuery?

Comment: @putvande , How? I've done it first in the chain. right?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. But try `.attr` instead of `.prop`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `attr()`, if you want to update the html. Using `prop()` updates the internal property of the dom element which may not reflect in the html

```js
value = ['<input type="checkbox" class="checkable" name="ids" value="315658">'];

value[0] = $(value[0]).attr('checked', true).prop('outerHTML');

snippet.log(value[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have question sir . Why don't we use prop? cause in the documentation its used multiple times for this purpose.

Comment: @RaminOmrani as I said in the answer comments, the `prop` method updates the `checked` property of the dom element which is not reflected in the html

Answer (score 1):

Try this hack

```
var checked = "checked ";
value = ['<input type="checkbox" class="checkable" name="ids" '+checked+'value="315658">'];
```

Comment: Actually at first I was going to do a string manipulation, but this wouldn't work in my app's criteria . I haven't mentioned the remaining code . thanks for the try.